# Why cocoa packet analyzer shows "capture packets to a trace file" menu?

Tags: macos, wireshark, packet, cocoa

I am trying to use 'cocoa packet analyzer'('C.P.A').

I uses mac OSX and I installed this from appstore.

After installed this, when I launch this program a popup comes out.

Others say that to get started analyzing use "capture packets to a trace file" menu.

But mine, has only 3 menus, and there are no such menu like that.

What I have is below.

-open trace file (it opens a file manager)
-preference (there is advanced tab. but it supplies nothing)
-help(does not help not at all)

How can I find that menu?

Thanks for answer :-)

P.S
I am using wifi - network. It can be a problem in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the current version 1.21 that for some reason misses the button "Capturing" (maybe only if no interfaces found). Take the older version 1.11 http://www.tastycocoabytes.com/_downloads/CPA_111.dmg, take a look:

[image]

[image]

Comment: indeed! now I have the button. Thanks a lot :-) But is there any clues why they remove this function in the newest version?

Comment: I don't know, probably the button is missing not always but in certain circumstances (e.g. no network interfaces found) ...

Answer (score 1):

The app store version is not able to capture any traffic. Use the one from [the website](http://www.tastycocoabytes.com/).